# How to auto initialize fields in a Django model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model in Django and basically I need to to auto initialize 3 out of 5 fields once the user has inserted some data, i.e.,

**Models.py**

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    assignment       = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    comments         = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    starting_date    = models.DateField()
    points           = models.IntegerField()
    STATUS = (('A', 'Active'), ('C', 'Cancelled'), ('D', 'Done'))
    status           = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Task

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        starting_date = datetime.now()
        fields = ['task_description', 'task_comments', 'starting_date', 'priority', 'points']
```

**Input form**

```
<!-- Input form to request to values-->
<div class="panel-heading">Add a new assignment </div>
  <form id ="insert_new_assign" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" name="insert_new_assign_field" type="text" placeholder="Insert your new assignment here" />
        <input class="form-control" name="insert_new_comment_field" type="text" placeholder="Any comment you want to add?" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[See the JS fiddle for quick reference](https://jsfiddle.net/rwkx6L0n/)

Basically when the user enters a new assignment and comment, **I want Django to save these two fields and auto initialize the other fields with the current time, 0 points and A status**. Whenever I try to to save a new record, I get the error `The view engine.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object` which is normal because Django expects from the user to complete all the fields and not only two.

**Previous research**

Based on some research, I found out that only [one field can be completed in a Django model](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-to-autofill-a-field-in-the-database) - the id - but at the same time they mention the `Custom Managers` which  are classes that can address the problem I have, however, [the examples they provide do not fit for my current situation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/).

**My main question is:**

How can I indicate in Django to save the two fields and auto initialize the other fields with the current date and time, 0 points and A status?

Any help in this questions will be greatly appreciated, feel free to improve this question as well.

Comment: For starting_time you can add auto_now_add to True in your model, For integer field add default to 0 and for status add the default id of status and also add blank and null in those case. In forms.py mark them with required = False.

Comment: So, the models.py should have `starting_date    = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)` something like this?

Comment: Yes. And also skip it from the form's field.

Comment: I have made some of your suggestions but I found out another problem: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: 'starting_date' cannot be specified for Task model form as it is a non-editable field
`. Is there any chance you can illustrate your code as an answer?

Comment: The problem you describe has nothing at all to do with your models or initialisation, but is entirely contained within the view, which you didn't post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some suggestions made from Bidhan, I was able to get the following code to bypass the problem.

```
from django.utils import timezone

class Assignment(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('A', 'Active'),
        ('C', 'Cancelled'),
        ('D', 'Done')
    )

    assignment       = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    comments         = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    starting_date    = models.DateField(default=timezone.now())
    points           = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    status           = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS, default='A')
```